# factory girl - Given Project, how to make permissions? Associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2, factory-bot

I have the following models:

```
Users (id)
Project (id, name)
Roles (id, title)
Permissions (user_id, role_id, project_id)
```

With Factory Girl I want to make a factory which includes 2 users, 1 project, and permissions associating the 2 users to the project.

Here's what I have so far:

```
Factory.define :user do |user|
  user.fname                  "James"
  user.lname                  "Bond"
  user.email                  "james.bond@intuit.com"
  user.password               "password"
  user.password_confirmation  "password"
end

Factory.define :project do |project|
  project.name              "myproject"
  project.private_email     "myproject"
  project.user_id do
    (User.find_by_email('james.bond@intuit.com')).id
  end
  project.instance_id do
    (User.find_by_email('james.bond@intuit.com')).instance_id
  end

  project.permissions {|permissions| [permissions.association(:permission)] }

end


Factory.define :permission do |permission|
  permission.role_id         1
  permission.creator_id do
    (User.find_by_email('james.bond@intuit.com')).id
  end  
  permission.user_id do
    (User.find_by_email('james.bond@intuit.com')).id
  end
  permission.project_id do
    (Project.find_by_name('myProject')).id
  end


end
```

But this errors with:

Failure/Error: @project = Factory(:project)
 RuntimeError:
   Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id

I'm new to factory girl, am I doing this right? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to take advantage of the association method to associate models with another.

You would do something like:

```
 project.user {|i| i.association(:user)}

 permission.creator {|i| i.association(:user)}
 permission.project {|i| i.association(:project)}
```

etc.

An example of this:

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.sequence(:email) { |n| "mike#{n}@awesome.com"}
  u.password "funnyguy1"
  u.password_confirmation {|u| u.password }
 end

Factory.define :profile do |p|
  p.sequence(:username) { |n| "madmike#{n}"}
  p.user {|i| i.association(:user)}
end
```

You would do something like this, for example:

```
Factory.define :permission do |permission|
  permission.role_id         1
  permission.creator {|i| i.association(:user)}
  permission.user {|i| i.association(:user)}
  permission.project {|i| i.association(:project)}
end
```

I would suggest reading the github page for FactoryGirl:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl

Comment: Where does this go? inside a Factory.define? or separate?

Comment: Is this friendly to Factory Girl Rails 3?

Comment: Yes, this is rails 3 compatible and it goes into the Factory.define

Comment: Thanks Mike, can you give a little more detail, maybe update? There are several defines in use?

Comment: Do I still use Factory.define :permission ?

Comment: Thanks Mike, but if I have 2 users, how do I make 2 permissions? do I have to use two Factory.define permission ?

Comment: Just posted an example for that as well.

Comment: Thanks Mike, not sure I'm seeing the example of given 2 users, how to make 2 unique permissions, one for each user ?

Comment: I would highly suggest checking out https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl for further explanation. It really elaborates on all your questions.

Comment: Thanks Mike, I see lots of examples for 1:1 like you show above, but not for the case when there are multiple users and each need a permission

Comment: You can do something like user1 = Factory.create(:user, :permissions => [Factory.create(:permission)]) and  user2 = Factory.create(:user, :permissions => [Factory.create(:permission)]) if you wanted to create two users with two separate permission.